# jQuery Select Checkbox When Text Exists, Hide Unselected Rows from Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a dynamically generated table that contains a checkbox for each row, some data, and a text input field.

I want to automatically check the checkbox for a selected row once text is entered in that row's textbox. Finally, when the 'Finish' button is pressed, I want any unselected rows to be hidden from printing. Final output will be the table containing only the selected rows (i.e. those with a check in the checkbox) and their values.

Here's the css print class to hide the unselected rows:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.grid .hidden tr {
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<table id="data" class="grid">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty to Order</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>Description data goes here</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputData"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
        <td>3454</td>
        <td>Description data goes here</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputData"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
        <td>6787</td>
        <td>Description data goes here</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputData"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="clicker">Finish</button>
```

Finally, here's the jQuery. This is selecting all the checkboxes when text is entered in a text field, not just the one for that row (which I don't understand), and not assigning the "hidden" class to the rows  without a checkbox - the class is not being assigned at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Check for input in text field
$('#data > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    $(".inputData").change(function() { 
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $(".check").prop("checked",true);
        } else {
            $("tr").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});

$("#clicker").click(function() {
        window.print();
        return false;
});
});


</script>
```

My logic in constructing this was to make sure we're only selecting rows in the table with an id of data. The first function will iterate over each row looking at the text field, and if the length of that field is greater than 0, check the box. Otherwise, assign the class of "hidden", which will prevent it from printing. Finally, simply assign a click event to the button.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9covoh57/)

Comment: are you trying this https://jsfiddle.net/9covoh57/3/?

Comment: No, that isn't hiding the unselected rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks or unchecks the appropriate box based on whether the input has a value:

```
$(".inputData").on('input', function () {
  var checkbox= $(this).closest('tr').find('[type="checkbox"]');
  checkbox.prop('checked', $(this).val());
});
```

It doesn't need to be within an `each()` method.

This hides all rows in which the checkboxes are not checked:

```
  $('[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide();
```

It makes sense to put that within the `$("#clicker").click()` function.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bs9ky61L/)

Comment: Thank you Rick - this works perfectly. I don't quite understand why you don't need to iterate over the rows though.

Comment: This applies to all the text inputs:  `$(".inputData").change(`.  Putting it within the `each()` doesn't make it apply to that particular row's input only.  Instead, my code determines which row the input applies to (using `closest('tr')`), and it then finds the checkbox on that row (using `find('[type="checkbox"]')`).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again.